# jQuery input name argument

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do we put `agru` inside function `$('input[name=agru]')`

```
 function changeBackground(agru){
      $('input[name=agru]').css('background','red');
}
```

`$('input[name=agru]')` isn't right. How do I escape? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
function addBorder(agru) {
    $('input[name=' + agru + ']').css('background', 'red');
}
```

Read [How do I concatenate a string with a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable-javascript)