# The Mathematical Operators not working on window.innerWidth

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I use mathematical operators with window.innerWidth it returs NaN.

I just tried to add numeric 1 to the window.innerWidth.
What's wrong with my code?

```
  <body>
   <p>Click the button to display this window's height and width (NOT including toolbars and scrollbars).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML = "Width: " + w-1 + " Heigth: " + h;
}
</script>
  </body>
```

[View sample at Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LJAKpYp1972jjKjE1IXm?p=preview)

Comment: Because there is no `innerwidth` property.

Comment: @hindmost: what makes you thinking so? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.innerWidth

Comment: javascript is case sensitive

Comment: @user1386579 make your innerHTML as `x.innerHTML = "Width: " + (w-1) + " Heigth: " + h;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your innerHTML code as

`x.innerHTML = "Width: " + (w-1) + " Heigth: " + h;`

Modify your **javaScript** code as below

Here is your modified [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dztft8YhR1XpeXGgQLTP?p=preview)

```
function myFunction() {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML = "Width: " + (w-1) + " Heigth: " + h;
}
```

[StackOverflow reference for '+' operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable-javascript#answer-4234569)

Comment: some people don't know what to do with their reputations