# How to add javascript value to an existing value of textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i want to generate a 6 digits and add them to an existing text such as :

this java script

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}</script>
```

it's output is random number ..

i want to add it to the text below in value

```
<input class="textbox"type="text" value="My Age is [ Here is The Output of the JavaScript] , am i old ?" >
```

is it possible ?

Comment: The text inside the textbox is always the same? _My age is <output>, am i old ?_

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo").value= "My Age is "+ x + ", am I old?";` Its called Concatenation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable

Comment: @Ema.jar yeah it's always the same

Comment: I've created a fiddle for you, let me know if it helps ;-)

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAzmy - If you want to ask another question, then ask another question; but do __not__ edit an existing question to ask something totally and completely different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "My Age is ["+x+"] , am i old ?";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace
  `document.getElementById("demo").value= x;`
to
 `document.getElementById("demo").value= "My Age is " + x + ", am i old ?";`

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a jsfiddle to see your code: https://jsfiddle.net/80rcowh3/3/

Basically I've added the id `"demo"` to your input. This is mandatory if you want to target the element using the function `getElementById`.

Than I've created the code to add your random number in the middle of the old text. At the end I put the new text in the input. You'll find comments on the code.

I hope it helps :-)