# object.style.transform="translateX(value)"; not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  //items[i].style.left = items[i].basicLeft + 100 * phase[i] + 'px';
  //console.log(items[i].style.left);
  var translation=items[i].basicLeft + 100 * phase[i] + 'px';
  console.log(translation);
  items[i].style.transform = 'translateX(translation)';
}
```

Here the `translateX` is not updating I tried using constants in place of  variable as an argument to `translateX` but there are no changes.

`console.log` for translation gives expected values.

If I use `style.left` the code which I have commented above the code works fine.

Comment: Title is wrong: it should read `object.style.transform`, not `object.style.transition`!

Comment: What if you do this: `items[i].style.transform = 'translateX(' + translation+ ')';`

Comment: Apparently, you have a typo in your code, it should be `items[i].style.transform`, not `items[i].transform`.

Comment: How should JavaScript know that `translation` in `'translateX(translation)'` should be replaced with the value of a variable?

Comment: @FelixKling Interpolation is great, but in this case, is it really a duplicate? ... maybe concatenate variable with string would be more appropriate? ... as in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable

Comment: @LGSon: I see "interpolation" is just a general term for "how can I insert a variable into this string", which is what the OP wants to do here, even if they didn't express it. Whether that happens through string concatenation or other means doesn't matter. I wasn't able to find a question that proposes string concatenation as an answer, but string concatenation is at least mentioned in the question itself. The question you linked to seems to be fine as well.