# Didn't understand the following keyword " +searchValue+ " in jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I encountered a program of jQuery on the internet.
It's aim was to highlight the text written in the inputbox
And I tried it myself , but I didn't understand the use of the following keyword in the program and why it was used in first the single quotes and then the double quotes and also why was it used with the plus sign in front and rear `'" +searchValue+ "'`

Below is the `html code`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <title>
         </title>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Search <br />
            <input type="text" id="search_text" />
        </p>
        <ul id="myList">
            <li>
                sweden
            </li>
            <li>
                tokyo
            </li>
            <li>
                istambul
            </li>
            <li>
                london
            </li>
            <li>
                paris
            </li>
        </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the `custom.css` code

```
body ul{
    padding-left: 0px;
}

ul li{
    list-style:none;
}

.highlight{
    background: #3bbf59;
}
```

Below is the code in `custom.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search_text').on('keyup',function(){
        var searchValue = $('#search_text').val();
        $('#myList li').removeClass('highlight');
        if($.trim('"+searchValue+"') !== ''){
            $("#myList li:contains('" +searchValue+ "')").addClass('highlight');
        }
    });
});
```

I am a beginner in jquery.

Comment: searchValue is a variable. The pluses are concatenation operators.

Comment: This is basic stuff that you could learn in any javascript tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable

Comment: I fully understand that it is used to concatenate and it is a variable but why are single and double quotes used there

Comment: where did you find this code? there seems to be something missing here `$.trim('"+searchValue+"')`

Comment: @RK Double quotes close and open the string. The single quotes are _part of_ the string.

Comment: This is from jquery tutorials of the newboston

Comment: @Turnip, what's the purpose of this then `$.trim('"+searchValue+"')`?

Comment: @Maximus no idea what that's about. Surely it should be `$.trim(searchValue)`

Comment: @Turnip, that's my point and I think that's what OP doesn't understand. Not the other usage inside `$(...)`

Comment: Then OP needs to write a clearer question.

Comment: @RK, which usage are you confused about? first or second

Comment: I was confused about both of them

Comment: i also had a doubt why can't I write `li:contains(searchValue)` in that code

Answer (score 1):

The first usage seems incorrect and it should probably be:

```
if($.trim(searchValue) !== ''){
```

to check if the value put into input is not space.

The second usage is just an application of concatenation operator (binary plus):

```
$("#myList li:contains('" +searchValue+ "')").addClass('highlight');
```

which will produce the string passed to jquery selector. If `seachValue='some'`, you'll have:

```
$("#myList li:contains('some')").addClass('highlight');
```