# How to write Google Sheets Script that searches my drive files for a variable search term entered in Cell B1 of my sheet?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm trying to write a google sheets script to search a series of my Drive files for a variable search term. My code works well as long as I consistently entitle my files that I want to search with "Joshs File". But I want to be able to search fullText by a variable search term entered in cell B1 of my sheet. What syntax do I use to do that?

fullText contains WHAT???

```
function SearchFiles() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh0 = sheet.getSheets()[0];
var search0 = sh0.getRange("B1").getValue();

  //Please enter your search term in the place of Letter
  var searchFor = 'title contains "Joshs File"' + 'and fullText contains "X"';
 var names =[];
  var fileIds=[];
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var name = file.getName();
    names.push(name);

  }

  for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    Logger.log(names[i]);


  }

  var body = Logger.getLog();
var range=sh0.getRange("A5");
range.setValue(body);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using implementing this code:

```
function SearchFiles(){
var textString = "Sample";
  
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(FolderID).searchFiles( 
      'fullText contains "'+textString+'"');
        while (files.hasNext()) {
          var file = files.next();
          Logger.log(file.getName());
      }

}
```

Just like how you [concatenate a variable and string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234857/5995040) you have to use "+" in order for it to be recognized as a variable.

Hope this helps.