# How to use Javascript variables within an HTML string segment

Tags: javascript

I am not sure how to phrase this question better but basically I am trying to do this:

```
v = v.replace(codelist[i], "<a href={converted}>{codelist[i]}</a>");
```

As you can see i'm just using regex to search for a certain string, and then replacing that string with a link. The problem here is "converted" and "codelist[i]" which I bracketed are variables, and I have no idea how to access them in this context.

I feel like I am missing something incredibly obvious here. Apologies if this is a duplicate question.

edit: this was marked as a duplicate for a question about string concatenation, which works to solve this problem as well, though it is far less elegant than the template strings solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate a string with a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable)

Comment: @juzraai I checked out the post you linked and I don't think it's related, what i needed was template strings which someone has already provided an answer for. Thanks.

Comment: @juzraai apologies, I see what you mean about my question being a duplicate now because string concatenation can also solve the problem I presented, though it was not what I had in mind at all so I just completely overlooked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template strings for this:

```
v = v.replace(codelist[i], `<a href=${converted}>${codelist[i]}</a>`);
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem, I did try using ${converted} before which didn't work because I missed out the grave accent symbol required to enclose the anchor tag instead of the quote marks.

Answer (score 1):

You have mainly 2 ways to do it:

1)

```
v = v.replace(codelist[i], "<a href={converted}>"+codelist[i]+"</a>");
```

2)

```
v = v.replace(codelist[i], `<a href={converted}>${codelist[i]}</a>`);
```

the main probelm with the 2nd way is that its not working on IE(who cares tbh :D)