# JavaScript adding variable to href

Tags: javascript

I have a json that is taking from a db information and showing as link, im trying to show the link from db but im gettig some issues, this is what i have:

```
 $("#content_div").html('<a href="'.knowledge_info.'"><h4 class="knowledge_base">Knowledge Info</h4></a>');
```

When doing this im getting :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

Not sure why, the variable is there, when doing console.log(knowledge_info); i can see the info coming from the variable

Comment: String concatenation in JS is done using `+`, not `.`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I concatenate a string with a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript string concatenation is with the `+` sign:

`$("#content_div").html('<a href="'+knowledge_info+'"><h4 class="knowledge_base">Knowledge Info</h4></a>');`

If your IDE doesn't show you this is syntactically wrong you should probably find another editor and check out some JS basics courses.

Comment: Don't forget to set my answer to accepted please :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you concatenate the string instead of using dots?

```
 $("#content_div").html('<a href="'+knowledge_info+'"><h4 class="knowledge_base">Knowledge Info</h4></a>');
```

Comment: Great, its fixed!

Answer (score 1):

if you use ES6 you can type like this

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content_div">
  run snippet
</div>
<script>
const knowledge_info = "href://yourlink"

$("#content_div").html(`
  <a href="${knowledge_info}">
   <h4 class="knowledge_base">Knowledge Info</h4>
  </a>
 `);
 </script>
```

and in js must be camelCase variables "knowledge_info"=>"knowledgeInfo"

Answer (score 0):

`.` operator is invalid in javascript.

It is used in `php` to combine string.

So you would replace `.` operator to `+`.

```
$("#content_div").html('<a href="'+knowledge_info+'"><h4 class="knowledge_base">Knowledge Info</h4></a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like so:

```
 $("#content_div").html(`<a href="${knowledge_info}"><h4 class="knowledge_base">Knowledge Info</h4></a>`);
```

:)