# Using a JavaScript variable in a CSS transform

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just starting out with JS so this is likely a newbie question. I am trying to figure out how to use a JS variable when using this line of code in my JS:

```
But3.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(JSVARIABLE)";
```

In my JS file I am running a function when a button is hovered over:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<div id= "But3" class="Button3"> </div>
</html>
```

When this button is hovered over (mouseover), the function is run in my JS code here:

**JS**

```
But3.onmouseover = function(){

  var h = document.getElementById("But3").clientHeight;
  var w = document.getElementById("But3").clientWidth;

  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
  var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

   /* This may be completely wrong*/
  var x = String(nh);
  var y = String (nw)

  /* This may also be completely wrong*/
  var nhf = x + "px";
  var nwf = y + "px";

  /* This works but I need it to work with nhf */
  But3.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(10px)";

}
```

How can I make it so that I can use my value `nhf` and `nwf` as the values for my `translateX` transform?

*Note that I may be incorrectly formatting the values since I convert them to a string in order to include "px".*

Here is my **CSS** if this is needed:

```
.Button3{
height: 20%;
  width: 17%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 20%;
  border-radius: 20%;
  background: #8585ad;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concat the variable in your value:

```
 But3.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(" + nhf + ")";
```

Answer (score 2):

As [jerrylow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669970/jerrylow) said, concatenate the variable into the string. This makes some of your excess code unnecessary

```js
document.getElementById("But3").onmouseover = function(){

  var h = document.getElementById("But3").clientHeight;
  var w = document.getElementById("But3").clientWidth;

  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
  var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

  // translateX should probably use nw instead of nh
  But3.style.webkitTransform = "translateX(" + nh + "px)";

}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Hover me" id="But3">
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that `nw` should be used w/ `translateX`

Answer (score 0):

You can use string interpolation within a template literal to accomplish this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals.

In your case, that would look like:

```
But3.style.webkitTransform = `translateX(${nhf})`;
```

Template literals were introduced in the ES2015 specification and are [supported by most major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals).