# Writing letter directly behind a value

Tags: javascript

I need to assign a time to a profile value from our database, but I don't know how to seperate the values.

It is the following code:

```
var pauze_datum = new Date("2020-01-27T10:33:00");
```

The time should be assigned to var Temporary_Date which is a filled in date in a form. How do you seperate the letter e and T?

```
var pauze_datum = new Date("Temporary_Date T10:33:00");
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `new Date(Temporary_Date + "T10:33:00");`?

Comment: Well, you can use string concatenation, `var pauze_datum = new Date(Temporary_Date + "T10:33:00");`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I concatenate a string with a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable)

Comment: Yes this is it exactly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either regular concatenation:

```js
var value = "2020-01-27";
var pauze_datum = new Date(value + "T10:33:00");
```

or template literals:

```js
var value = "2020-01-27";
var pauze_datum = `${value}T10:33:00`;
```