# When setting the position of an svg element, in javascript, how to do the "px"?

Tags: javascript, svg

Say you have a simple fullscreen div

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
</body>
```

and

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
html, body { width:100%; height:100%; } /* ensure full screen*/
<style>
    div {
        display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

and then in javascript

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper')
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

If you want to **add an svg dot on the screen**, you would:

(A) make an svg element (for convenience we'll just make it the same size as the circle itself, say 20.20)

```
console.log("making new dot at 313.172")

onedot = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'svg')
onedot.setAttribute('width', 20)
onedot.setAttribute('height', 20)

onedot.style.position = 'absolute'
onedot.style.left = 312
onedot.style.top = 172
```

(B) inside the element, just add the one stroke, being the circle.

```
var cc = document.createElementNS(svgns, "circle")
cc.setAttribute("cx", 10)
cc.setAttribute("cy", 10)
cc.setAttribute("r", 10)
cc.setAttribute("fill", "blue")

onedot.appendChild(cc)

wrapper.appendChild(onedot)
```

This does seem to work fine. You can now go wild drawing dots all over the place:

[image]

My problem, right here you're dealing with "real world" so to speak values, not just the whacky svg space stuff:

```
onedot.style.position = 'absolute'
onedot.style.left = 312
onedot.style.top = 172
```

That's going in the div.

in my limited understanding of DOM, HTML etc. it's really essential to specify such values as "px"

**How to specify px there?**

Is there a way?

Comment: You can do this onedot.style.left = '312px';

Comment: Or `312 + 'px'`

Comment: My God.  Is that true - you're pulling my leg ??

Comment: If so, thank you so much !  Seems hard to believe !

Comment: increedible @Grumpy and Heretic pls. put in an answer so I can bounty it.  May help googlers in the future too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I concatenate a string with a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable)

Comment: thanks @HereticMonkey you know I believe for any non-www programmers, like me, this question is considerably clearer, the other one is more of a superset of this information for experts !!! heh!   bounty en route ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onedot.style.position = 'absolute'
onedot.style.left = 312
onedot.style.top = 172
```

change to

```
onedot.style.position = 'absolute';
onedot.style.left = '312px'; // both are oke
onedot.style.top = 172+'px'; // is ok to
```