# html virtual keys scan with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a simple web-based drink order app for just practicing. as you can see, I have to get and scan all drink keys value to find out which drink user selected.

But the problem is in for loop when I want to read every three keys at once with `document.getElementById` and save it into a variable(array). this doesn't work because the browser can not recognize the "bi" as I found in browser debug console. I set the "i" beside "b" because I want to check every single key in every cycle of the for loop.

What solution can you offer for this issue or what would you do if you want do such a project like this?

```js
function drinkOrder() {

  var drinkType, i = 1;

  for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) { //this is for drinks key scan to find out which drink user select.
    drinkType = document.getElementById('pi').innerText;
    drinkType = parseInt(drinkType);
  }

  if (drinkType == 1) {
    alert('you choosed coffee!');
  }

  if (drinkType == 2) {
    alert('you choosed tea!');
  }

  if (drinkType == 3) {
    alert('you choosed hot water!');
  }

}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

p {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="coffeMachine">

  <button id="b1" onclick="drinkOrder()" value="1"> coffee
    <p id="p1"> 1 </P>
  </button>

  <button id="b2" onclick="drinkOrder()"> tea
    <p id="p2"> 2 </p>
  </button>

  <button id="b3" onclick="drinkOrder()">  hot water
    <p id="p3"> 3  </P>
  </button>

</div>
```

[here is an screen shot of browser error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8oWJ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I concatenate a string with a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable)

Comment: There is no element with id = `pi`. So `document.getElementById('pi')` will return `null`. And null doesn't have `innertext` property. If it does not have then it can't be read. Henceforth the error.

Comment: In the future, please provide errors as text, not as pictures of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```js
function drinkOrder() {

  var drinkType, i = 1;

  for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) { //this is for drinks key scan to find out which drink user select.
    drinkType = document.getElementById('p' + i).innerText;
    drinkType = parseInt(drinkType);
  }

  if (drinkType == 1) {
    alert('you choosed coffee!');
  }

  if (drinkType == 2) {
    alert('you choosed tea!');
  }

  if (drinkType == 3) {
    alert('you choosed hot water!');
  }

}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

p {
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="coffeMachine">

  <button id="b1" onclick="drinkOrder()" value="1"> coffee
                <p id="p1"> 1 </P>
            </button>

  <button id="b2" onclick="drinkOrder()"> tea
                <p id="p2"> 2 </p>
            </button>

  <button id="b3" onclick="drinkOrder()">  hot water
                <p id="p3"> 3  </P>
            </button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the function a number as a parameter and this would work like this:

```js
function drinkOrder(drinkType) {

  if (drinkType == "1") {
    alert('you choosed coffee!');
  }

  if (drinkType == "2") {
    alert('you choosed tea!');
  }

  if (drinkType == "3") {
    alert('you choosed hot water!');
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="coffeMachine">

  <button id="b1" onclick="drinkOrder('1')" value="1"> coffee
                <p id="p1"> 1 </P>
            </button>

  <button id="b2" onclick="drinkOrder('2')"> tea
                <p id="p2"> 2 </p>
            </button>

  <button id="b3" onclick="drinkOrder('3')">  hot water
                <p id="p3"> 3  </P>
            </button>

</div>
```

Comment: Answers which explain why code was modified are downvoted less often than those which simply say "Try" and  spill code out onto the page.

Answer (score 0):

you should concat like that

```
drinkType = document.getElementById('p'+i).innerText;
```

Or you can use class on all buttons and make a loop

for example

```
<button class="btn">1</button>
<button class="btn">2</button>
<button class="btn">3</button>
```

script

```
btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
btn.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() => {
    value = item.innerText
  }
}
```

Comment: `querySelector` returns a single `Element`, which does not have a `forEach` method on it. You probably meant `querySelectorAll`. Also, arrow functions are constructed without the `function` keyword, and functions are constructed without arrows (`=>`). Pick one.