# Problem with location.pathname.split('/')

Tags: javascript, html

It returns the **text** `"window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]"` instead the REAL `pathname`, how could I solve it?

```
  <script>
     document.getElementById("categoria").innerHTML = 
     "<li style='display:inline;margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;' class='navbithome'> <a href='index.php{vb:raw session.sessionurl_q}' accesskey='1'><img src='{vb:stylevar imgdir_misc}/navbit-home.png' alt='{vb:rawphrase home}' /></a></li>" + "<a href='javascript:history.back()'>window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]</a>";
  </script>
```

Comment: Do it like this {window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]}

Comment: Happens the same thing, it shows the code and not the real path :/

Comment: Try putting append instead of innerHTML and the li inside the append  as.append(<li></li>)

Comment: Now nothing is showed

Comment: Can you put ur code on code pen and share the link

Answer (score 0):

You must concatenate `window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]` with the string you're assigning to `document.getElementById("categoria").innerHTML`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable) to know how to concatenate strings and variables. In the snippet below, I use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
document.getElementById("categoria").innerHTML =
  `<li style='display:inline;margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;' class='navbithome'>
    <a href='index.php{vb:raw session.sessionurl_q}' accesskey='1'>
      <img src='{vb:stylevar imgdir_misc}/navbit-home.png' alt='{vb:rawphrase home}' />
    </a>
  </li>
  <a href='javascript:history.back()'>${window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]}</a>`;
```

```html
<ul id="categoria"></ul>
```