# How to insert value after specific text in the string

Tags: javascript, string, slice

I would like to add value to my URL after the specific text. How I can achieve this?

I found a solution where I can slice and add values but I don't have the index fixed in this URL.

```
const url = 'www.website.com/api/test1/test2';

const url = 'www.website.test.com/api/test1/test2/test3';

const output1 = 'www.website.com/api/ha/test1/test2';

const output2 = 'www.website.test.com/api/ha/test1/test2/test3';
```

Comment: What is the "specific text"? You say you found a solution where you can slice and add values but don't show it. The index can be specified as the output of a function, so you don't need a fixed value. There are literally hundreds of questions about this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I concatenate a string with a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable)

Comment: Or [How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/736513/215552)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a certain value after a certain string you can simply replace the known value with the new string:

```
url.replace('/api', '/api/ha')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a fixed index, you should use Regex to search the string. Could look like this:

```
/(www.\D+\/api\/)[\D\d\/]+/gm
```

This code would put the before and after into a group and you can then do

```
group1 + yourstring + group2
```

to add it together.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer working with [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```js
const url1 = new URL('https://www.website.com/api/test1/test2');
const pn =  url1.pathname.split("/")
pn.splice(2,0,'ha')
url1.pathname=pn.join("/");
console.log(url1.href)
```