# Creating a field in an a object if it doesn't exist, incrementing it if it does if it does, for multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a collection "users"

```
{
  "id": "u101",
  "notifications": {}
},


{
  "id": "u102",
  "notifications": {"channelId": 1}
},
```

There's a notifications field that has an object. Every field of this object corresponds to a chat channel ID and they value is the amount of notifications in the channel (unread messages).

If user **"u101"** and **"u102"** are both in the the same channel and they recieve a notification, I'd need to create a **"channelId"** field for user **"u101"** and set the value to **1**. I'd also need to update the value for user "u102" and set the value of **"channelId"** to **2**

The expected result is as follows:

```
{
  "id": "u101",
  "notifications": {"channelId": 1}
},


{
  "id": "u102",
  "notifications": {"channelId": 2}
},
```

I have tried doing it by simply querying the "users" collection, getting the array with the users back and then looping over it with ES6 functions like this:

```
users.forEach(user => {
            user.notifications.hasOwnProperty(channelId) ?
                user.notifications[channelId]++
                :
                user.notifications[channelId] = 1
        })
```

It works well but the problem is that I need to update all the users one by one in a loop with

```
collection.updateOne({ '_id': user._id }, { $set: user })
```

And it can amount to a LOT of users in one channel. Is there a way to this with one MongoDB command?

Comment: I think the main thing you're looking for here is the `$in` operator for the query portion of the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$inc` in order to increment or create the value (if not exists) to all wanted documents in a single query:

```
db.collection.update(
  {},
  {$inc: {"notifications.channelId": 1}},
  {multi: true}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jHQOvle4c64)

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much! Never thought it would be so simple

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically change the "channelId"?. There could be different channelIds but this statically with literally "channelId", when channel Id could be any _id

Comment: @BorisRyjkov See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234533/how-do-i-concatenate-a-string-with-a-variable

Comment: Nevermind - I found a solution in another question!